# Deep/recursive firebase query

Tags: javascript, firebase, recursion, firebase-realtime-database

How can I recursive query key with [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base)?

I have the follow structure..

```
comments/{ROOM_ID}: {
    {COMMENT_ID}: { 
        <COMMENT_DATA> 
        comments: { 
            <OTHERS_REPLIED_COMMENTS> 
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

And I want to push new replied comment ... I tried:

```
export async function addReplyComment(roomId, parentCommentKey, data) {
  const parentComment = await base.fetch(`comments/${roomId}`, {
    asArray: true,
    queries: {
      equalTo: parentCommentKey,
      orderByKey: 'comments', // 'RIGHT? OR MAYBE orderByChild ?',
    },
  });

  return base.push(`${parentComment.<FULL_PATH_HERE, HOW?>}/comments`, {
    data,
  });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see what your JSON looks like. Can you give a real snippet of JSON from your database? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I added an image

Comment: From the JSON you shared, there is no path `comments/${roomId}/comments`. There **is** a `comments/${roomId}/$someOtherPushId/comments`, but that's not what you're querying. I have a feeling you're trying to do the same as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code.